# Is it possible to detect whether text has been cut and pasted into a textbox on a webpage?

Tags: jquery, ajax, client-side, cut-and-paste

Is it possible using some sort of client side code to detect cut and paste?

The only solution I can think of is to constantly get the text length and if it changes drastically over a certain period, then assume text was pasted.

Comment: what amount of text are we talking, cause I type pretty fast :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the only way you'd know if the text changed through all the crazy ways text can be inserted into a textbox might be to monitor the value in an Interval...checking for when the next interval value was different from the previous...that would detect any form of change but it isn't a very neat solution (seems overkill)...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Add a keydown event listener and look for keyCode 86 and e.ctrlKey == true.  It looks like this has been asked and answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232115/hook-paste-event-to-hidden-textarea) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441631/how-to-detect-right-mouse-click-paste-using-javascript)

Comment: If the purpose is just to detect if a text was pasted i will use both suggested ways:

the one from umop, watching when the V key and control key are pressed simultaneously and if some text have incremented drastically...

Comment: what if you go Edit - Paste from the menu though?

Comment: i paste with the middle mouse button

Comment: Found another, more exhaustive post.  Edited my answer to suit.